# dynamically Frame the URl in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

In c# i need to frame the folllowing URL dynamically,here Action is redirectURL and the Controller is Books,when i post the page i send the url to some other page in follwing format.is it posible to frame the URL with "localhost:7187" dynamically?
http://localhost:7187/Books/redirectURL

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand. Could you add some code to better explain your situation?

Comment: what do you mean by "frame the url" ?

Answer (score 0):

Folllwing way i framed the url(http://localhost:7187/Books/redirectURL)  dynamically

Classname.WebsitePath + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(Url.Action("redirectURL", "Books"));

public static string WebsitePath 
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            }
        }